# CSV import functionalityfor button not working for multiple related fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Following is my query .

```
SELECT PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.IsCustom, PermissionSet.Label, PermissionSet.PermissionsApiEnabled, Assignee.Name, Assignee.Id, Assignee.Profile.Name, Assignee.ProfileId, Assignee.UserRoleId, Assignee.UserRole.Name,Assignee.Profile.UserType, SystemModstamp, Assignee.isActive FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
       Where Assignee.isActive = True AND permissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE 
       ORDER BY Assignee.Name
```

I want multiple related fields in custom export button but i am stuck here

Following is my code

```
convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV : function(component,objectRecords){
        // declare variables
        var csvStringResult, counter, keys, columnDivider, lineDivider;

        // check if "objectRecords" parameter is null, then return from function
        if (objectRecords == null || !objectRecords.length) {
            return null;
         }
        // store ,[comma] in columnDivider variabel for sparate CSV values and 
        // for start next line use '\n' [new line] in lineDivider varaible  
        columnDivider = ',';
        lineDivider =  '\n';

        // in the keys valirable store fields API Names as a key 
        // this labels use in CSV file header  
        keys = ['Assignee','PermissionSetId','AssigneeId','PermissionSet','Assignee'];

        csvStringResult = '';
        csvStringResult += keys.join(columnDivider);
        csvStringResult += lineDivider;

        for(var i=0; i < objectRecords.length; i++){   
            counter = 0;

             for(var sTempkey in keys) {
                var skey = keys[sTempkey] ;  

              // add , [comma] after every String value,. [except first]
                  if(counter > 0){ 
                      csvStringResult += columnDivider; 
                   }   

               if(typeof objectRecords[i][skey] === 'object')
               {
                    csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].Name+'"';


                 }

          //   else
           //  {
             //  csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].IsActive+'"';   
            // }

               else
                 {
                    csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey]+'"';            
                     }

               counter++;

            } // inner for loop close 
             csvStringResult += lineDivider;
          }// outer main for loop close 

       // return the CSV formate String 
        return csvStringResult;        
    }
})

Iam able to fetch assignee.name but how to get three related fields like 
Assignee.UserRole.Name

following is my custom code for component too
<th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!perm.Assignee.Name}">{!perm.Assignee.Name}</div>
      </th>

      <th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!perm.Assignee.Profile.Name}">{!perm.Assignee.Profile.Name}</div>
      </th>

       <th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}</div>
      </th> 

        <th scope="row">
       <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.Assignee.UserRole.Name}</div>
      </th> 

       <th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.Assignee.IsActive}</div>
      </th>
```

Comment: what is attribute type using for `Assignee` in your component?

Comment: This is the attribute which is using

Comment: <aura:attribute name="Permissiontable" type="PermissionSetAssignment" />

Comment: any help will be appreciated

Comment: r u using  `Permissiontable`  field for `auta:iteration`? can you add full code like what is return type of your ` Apex` method and where to bind to `aura:attribute` other wise you won't get much answers for question

Comment: here is my apex class

Comment: can you give me your gmail link or provide me linkedin id their i can discuss

Comment: iam unable to paste full code here can you come online in linkedin?

Comment: public class Persmissionset {
     public static List<PermissionSetAssignment> permissonAssignment()
    { List<PermissionSetAssignment> PermissionList=new List<PermissionSetAssignment>
     ([SELECT PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.IsCustom, PermissionSet.Label, PermissionSet.PermissionsApiEnabled, Assignee.Name, Assignee.Id, Assignee.Profile.Name, Assignee.ProfileId, Assignee.UserRoleId, Assignee.UserRole.Name,Assignee.Profile.UserType, SystemModstamp, Assignee.isActive FROM PermissionSetAssignment]);
     return PermissionList;
      
    }
}